# Installing Emacs from source: no 'configure' file

Tags: install, build

I wish to build the latest development version of Emacs from source. I've browsed to https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/emacs and executed the command suggested on the front page, namely

```
git clone -b master git://git.sv.gnu.org/emacs.git
```

I then read the INSTALL file, which says

> 2a. 'cd' to the directory where you unpacked Emacs and invoke the
>         'configure' script:
>
> ```
>    ./configure
> ```

I followed these instructions, but this resulted in the following error message:

> -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Inspecting the directory where I unpacked Emacs, I see that there is indeed no file named 'configure'. The closest matches are the files 'config.bat' and 'configure.ac'.

Why isn't there a 'configure' file in my installation directory? How do I proceed from here?

---

I run macOS Sierra version 10.12.5 .

Comment: `INSTALL`: For information about building from a Git checkout (rather than an Emacs release), read the `INSTALL.REPO` file first. These files are in the base directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line only applies to release tarballs (hence why it says "unpacked") which come with a `configure` script.  For the git checkout you'll need to generate it with `./autogen.sh`.  Be sure to check out the `README` file for more instructions.