# Installing Emacs from source: 'make' fatal error: 'libxml/tree.h' file not found

Tags: install

I wish to run Emacs from the latest development version.

I've downloaded the latest Emacs development version from https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/emacs (with `git clone -b master git://git.sv.gnu.org/emacs.git`), ran `autogen.sh` as suggested [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/34232/4084), then followed the instructions on the screen: after `autogen.sh` I executed `./autogen.sh git`, then `./configure`, and finally `make` (if I run `make install` instead, I get the same error message as below). All the steps except `make` seemed to finish successfully.

As for `make`, it started off well enough, but at some point it stopped with the following error message:

```
xml.c:23:10: fatal error: 'libxml/tree.h' file not found
#include <libxml/tree.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [xml.o] Error 1
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

My path includes `/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4_3/include/libxml2`, and this directory in turn contains `libxml/tree.h`.

How can I fix the problem?

---

I run macOS Sierra version 10.12.5 .

Comment: Install the `libxml` library (through homebrew)?

Comment: @Dan: `libxml` is not available via Homebrew.

Comment: @Dan: However `libxml2` *is* available through Homebrew. Will it do?

Comment: FWIW, the sequence is `make` (to build the executable and everything else) *and* `make install` (to install the built executable and the rest).

Comment: @wasamasa: I just followed the instructions that appeared on the screen at the end of each step starting with `autogen.sh`.

Comment: If you are on OSX, why are you not using `./configure --with-ns`?  And, why are you not using `make` prior to calling `make install`?

Comment: @lawlist: To answer your first question: because the nextstep/INSTALL file says: "On macOS, --with-ns is enabled by default." To answer your second question:  I just followed the instructions that appeared on the screen at the end of each step starting with `autogen.sh`, and they didn't mention to run `make`, only `make install`. But I'll run `make` now.

Comment: @lawlist: `make` results in the same error message as the one I reported in my original post.

Comment: @lawlist: I should add that my path includes `/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4_3/include/libxml2`, and this directory contains `libxml/tree.h`, so I'm really perplexed.

Comment: @lawlist: I executed `./config --with-ns` per your suggestion, and then `make`, but I get the same error message.

Comment: @lawlist Maybe the "2" in the directory name is the culprit? Trying it out with a symlink might help.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10: Per your suggestion I created a symlink: `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4_3/include/libxml2 /usr/local/bin/include` and added it to my path before the original entry that the symlink is based on. Alas, I get the same error message.

Comment: This looks interesting:  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-11/msg01940.html -- I'm not 100% certain it is applicable, but the bottom line of that particular thread is: "*you are missing the command line tools for OSX. Try running `xcode-select --install` from the command line*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message described in the question has previously been encountered by other fellow Emacs enthusiasts, and the recommended fix is to install OSX command line tools by running the following from the command line:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Here is the link to the Emacs development thread that described the above solution by Daniel Sutton:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-11/msg01940.html

Comment: This solution does not work since macOS 10.14

Comment: You can get the command line tools for 10.14 Mojave from the download site here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/  Then you'll be able to install the headers as below in @carlbolduc's answer.

Answer (score 27):

The accepted answer does not work anymore since libxml2 will be installed inside the XCode directory. The solution is described here:

https://silvae86.github.io/sysadmin/mac/osx/mojave/beta/libxml2/2018/07/05/fixing-missing-headers-for-homebrew-in-mac-osx-mojave/

In short, Apple provides an installer that can put the librairies inside `/usr/include`. You can copy this installer to your desktop by doing this:

```
cp /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg ~/Desktop
```

Once copied, just launch the installer from your Desktop.

Comment: This also works for the make error in openconnect

Comment: this worked for me on new 10.14.4

Answer (score 2):

I successfully built emacs 26.3 from scratch on macOS 10.15.1 with libxml2 installed using `brew` without the nonsense in the first two answers. After installing libxml2 and running `./configure`, I modified the `CFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` in `emacs-26.3/src/Makefile` to terminate with libxml2 instead of include:

```
CFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2
CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2
```

Comment: Another way to run this is:

`CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2" CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2 make install`

Comment: @rgiar I'm old school, I like to keep a record of how it the binary was built so when I come back to recompile a year later I don't have to work this problem again.